# VS 2010 Crashes while working with .rdlc

Tags: programming-languages

I am trying to create report using Microsoft reporting technology using Visual Studio 2010. I added .rdlc file to the solution. The solution has huge number of files.

The problem is Visual Studio 2010 crashes everytime I select to add new dataset in report in design view. Please suggest some solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options:

1. Upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 SP1.
   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5&displaylang=en
2. Look at your resource utilization and see if you are running out of resources when you add a new datasource.
3. Split your larger solution into smaller solutions.

Also, something to try and narrow down the problem would be to create a new solution, and go through the same steps, and see if your environment still crashes.

If it does, look in the event logs and see if you can find the error, then either research that error, or post it here, so we can help further.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by checking class library (.dll) that do data access layer
and recompile it from Framework 2.0 to 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing this exact same issue today, the whole day!

I did a bit of digging around, and debugging, and found that Report Designer is looking for MVC3, which is not installed!

Debugging shows me the following:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Controls.dll

Additional information: 
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I downloaded MVC3 from:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491

and after restarting VS 2013, it all went ok!

Please let me know if this helps you too